# Aurelia - I18N on options of a select

Tags: internationalization, aurelia, i18next

I would like to translate the options of my select but I do not know how to do that :

```
<select>
    <option repeat.for="element of elementList" model.bind="element.id">
      ${element.value}   <== How to translate the value ?
    </option>
</select>
```

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value would have to be a key in your translation file. Then you'd simply use the `t` binding behavior:

`${element.value & t}`

This would work for a `model.bind` expression as well, but that might not be what you want.

Comment: Awesome ! Works perfectly ! Please, tell me : how would you explain the '&' ? What is its meaning ?

Comment: The `&` is how you specify that the next thing in your binding expression is going to be a Binding Behavior. You can learn more about Binding Behaviors, including the ones that come with the framework here: https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/binding-behaviors